How to solve the recurrence $T(n) = \sum T(k) + 2(n-1)$
We have the recurrence:
$$T(n) = 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (T(k) + 1)$$
What function $T(n)$ satisfies this?

Context: This recurrence comes up when trying to count the number of multiplications performed by the recursive matrix chain method without memoization described in section 15.3 of the "Introduction to Algorithms" book by Cormen et.al. (3rd edition). Here is Python code implementing it.
import numpy as np

def matrix_chain(p, i, j, m):
    if i == j:
        return 0
    m[i, j] = np.inf
    for k in range(i, j):
        # The recurrence in equation (x) above.
        q = matrix_chain(p, i, k, m) + matrix_chain(p, k+1, j, m) +\
            p[i-1]*p[k]*p[j]
        if q < m[i, j]:
            m[i, j] = q
    return m[i, j]

if __name__ == "__main__":
  p = [30, 35, 15, 5, 10, 20, 25]
  n = len(p) - 1
  m = np.zeros((n+1, n+1))
  mm = matrix_chain(p, 1, n, m)
  print(m)

Included below is an image of the tree of recursive calls for that algorithm (the integers in brackets are the $i$ and $j$ parameters). Each branch of two involves two multiplications. Note also that we only care about the number of matrices in the sub-chain which is $j-i+1$. And this is what leads to the recurrence in question.


Hint: If $$ S(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n T(k)$$
then $T(n) = S(n) - S(n-1)$, and your recurrence says
$$ S(n) - S(n-1) = 2 S(n-1) + 2 $$

Thanks. This looks exponential. However, I had forgotten a bracket in the recurrence. The 2 was inside the summation. With that, I get $S(n) = 3 S(n-1) +2(n-1)$. I guess this can be done with the master method.
